# Minimum of $x^TWx$

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, solution-verification, symmetric-matrices

I have one question on the proof of the problem below.

For any symmetric matrix $W$, the minimum of $x^TWx$ when $||x||_2 = 1$ is achieved at the eigenvector $v_n$ corresponding to the minimum eigen value $\lambda_n$.

The proof is as follows.

Let $\lambda_1\geq\dots\geq\lambda_n$ be the eigenvalues of $W$ and its corresponding orthonormal eigenvecotrs $v_1,\dots,v_n$.

Letting $x=\alpha_1v_1+\dots+\alpha_n v_n$ where $\alpha_1^2+\dots+\alpha_n^2=1$.
$$x^TWx = \alpha_1^2\lambda_1+\dots \alpha_n^2\lambda_n\geq (\alpha_1^2+\dots+\alpha_n^2)\lambda_n = \lambda_n$$

Taking $\alpha_n=1$, the inequality is achieved. However what I can't understand is that how can we assure that $\lambda_n$ becomes the minimum? There might be some $z$ such that
$x^TWx \geq \lambda_n \geq z$.

How to prove that there aren't any $x$ such that $x^TWx=z$?

Comment: Take a normed eigenvector for this eigenvalue.

Comment: Well, *the proof you quoted* is what tells you no such $x$ exists. It has to take the form $x = \alpha_1 v_1 + \cdots + \alpha_n v_n$ where $\alpha_1^2 + \cdots + \alpha_n^2 = 1$, and the inequality shows that $x^\top W x \ge \lambda_n > z$. Is there a step you don't understand?

Comment: How do we know $\lambda_n$ becomes the global minimum?

Comment: I updated the post!

Answer (score 3):

> However what I can't understand is that how can we assure that λn becomes the minimum?

This is assured through the inequality
$$\alpha_1^2\lambda_1+\dots \alpha_n^2\lambda_n\geq (\alpha_1^2+\dots+\alpha_n^2)\lambda_n$$
There really is no way to pick an $x$, which is to say a collection of $\alpha_i$, that breaks this inequality. As long as this inequality holds, the inequality $x^TWx\geq \lambda_nx^Tx$ will hold. Because those two inequalities are really the same inequality written in two different ways.

Comment: Ah ok I think I understood. Thank you!